# Find and replace lower to upper case not work

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text  :

```
 the_historical_date := (the_study_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'c_historical_date')::TIMESTAMP;

 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'c_testdate')
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'C_sdad')
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'C_sDad')
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'C_AAA')
```

and a regex to find and convert upper case to lower case

> Regex  : '[c|C]_[a-z][^)\s]*'
>
> Replace: \U$1

But when I click 'Replace All' or 'Replace', it's replace by an empty string

```
 the_historical_date := (the_study_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>)::TIMESTAMP;

 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>)
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>)
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>)
 udy_fwd_queue_pkg_var->>'C_AAA')
```

[image]

What's wrong with my procedure?

Comment: You have no capturing group in the pattern, `$1` is an empty string. What is the expected result? If you need to replace with the match itself, you may use `\U$0` or there are other options, see linked thread.

Comment: Replace with the full match `\U$&` You can shorten the pattern to `[cC]_[a-z][^)\s]*`

Comment: Thanks to @WiktorStribiżew and The fourth bird both your answers worked fine!